# How does Python execute files without the .py extension?

Tags: python, file-extension

How is Python able to execute files without the .py extension?  Both the files below work.  How does Python know that `hello.txt` is a Python file?

`hello.py`:

```
print "hello world"
```

`hello.txt`:

```
print "hello world"
```

```
$ python hello.txt
hello world

$ python hello.py
hello world
```

Comment: Because file extensions don't really mean anything. If it's a valid python file, it's a valid python file regardless of the extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python knows it is a Python file because you ran `python <name of file>`. File extensions don't actually matter very much to computers. File extensions help you, the human, remember what kind of file something is. They also make it easier for computers to automatically figure out what program to use for a particular file.

But really, file extensions simply don't matter if you want to ignore them. If you tell Python to open a file, it's gonna try to open that file. It doesn't care what the name of the file is; all that matters is if the file contains valid Python code.

Comment: I don't know how Python behaves on Windows because I always use it on Linux, but I can see how this would be surprising to Windows users. Python uses file extensions in a very Linuxy way -- as a hint, at best, but usually to be totally ignored. This might be a foreign concept to someone who has grown up using only Windows, where file extensions are used more heavily by the OS and treated like they really mean something.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - It's the same way on Windows. The extension just indicates which program should open the file by default. The big warning is only there to avoid having to help non-power users figure out why their Word file isn't opening in Word anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows and asking about the actual Python executables, then you can specify which executable Python will use with the `.py` extension.

For example, from the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) you can run associate Python scripts as follows from the command prompt:

`assoc .py=Python.File`

Then, if you wanted to use pythonw.exe instead of python.exe to execute your Python scripts, you can change the executable with this command:

```
ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\pythonw.exe "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 2):

The python interpreter, as well as other programs/interpreters/etc (i.e. ruby, bash, etc), don't really care about the file extension, they just try to execute the file content and expect it to comply with the syntax of the language such program uses, throwing appropriate errors otherwise.

Example with ruby, consider the next file `hello.hello`:

```
puts 'Hello in ruby'
```

you can run it as:

```
$ ruby hello.hello
Hello in ruby
```

---

In addition to your example, note that you can also run the same file with no extension at all and without specifying in the command line the program that shall run your file; however in this case you would need to specify so in the file itself, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Hello world!'
```

and run it

```
$ ./hello
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

`py`, `txt` and many other files are all technically "text" files. However, the extensions serve as a way for the user and the OS to differentiate between which file is for what programs. If you use Mac or Windows, you may sometimes get a screen `open with` where you can choose a default program to open a file. In order to know what program to use on what file, the operating system uses file extensions.

You can use file extensions in order to know what file does what. A `py` file is known to run as Python and you launch `.docx` as Microsoft Word. But what if both of these were text files? You can get some serious encoding errors if opening a Microsoft Word file in Python :P